# What are the open source alternatives for Facebook?

Tags: facebook, open-source, clone, social-networking

Just want to look at how things are implemented for learning purpose and may even contribute something along the way. So is there any open source facebook clones out there ?

Thanks

Comment: How is this not constructive? Surely a list of open source projects that provide similar functionality to Facebook is factual, can be supported with references (git hub source for example) and a social media expert would be able to provide those facts?

Comment: http://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Searching](http://www.google.nl/search?aq=1&oq=open+source+faceboo&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=open+source+facebook+alternative) gives

1. [Diaspora](https://joindiaspora.com/)
2. [OneSocialWeb](http://onesocialweb.org/)

as starting points, a list of active distributed social media sites can be found [here](http://we-need-a-free-and-open-social-network.wikispaces.com/Active+Distributed+Social+Networks)

Comment: the last link is expired

Answer (score 2):

This one is most polished right now: http://elgg.org/

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a 'clone' but Diaspora is an open source, decentralised, distributed alternative to Facebook.

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora
https://joindiaspora.com/